# Convert from microseconds to hour, minutes, seconds and milliseconds

Tags: algorithm, date, datetime, pseudocode

I need to pass from microseconds (saved inside a `unsigned long long int` variable) to its representation as hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds, that is:

```
from 47072349659 to 13:04:32.350
```

I found [this conversion from milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874048/from-milliseconds-to-hour-minutes-seconds-and-milliseconds), but I don't seem to manage to make it work in my case. Maybe the problem is that the number is too long to be stored in certain variable type? I'm using `unsigned long long int` for input time and tried int, long, unsigned long long int for outputs.

Here is my C++ code:

```
unsigned long long int timestamp;

long milliseconds   = (long) (timestamp / 1000000) % 1000;
long seconds    = (long) ((timestamp / (1000)) % 60);
long minutes    = (long) ((timestamp / (60000)) % 60);
long hours      = (long) ((timestamp / (3600000)) % 24);
```

Comment: Which language? Show some code.

Comment: Any language. I'm writing in c++, but I just want the pseudocode. I'm trying to use the code shown on the link I provided, but it's not working for microseconds.

Comment: You're doing something wrong. Manual calculations show that your numbers are OK and a 64-bit integer is definitely enough. Show us your code.

Comment: Sorry, I copied the first number from the wrong line. Anyway I corrected the numbers and I added my code.

Comment: why do you devide by 1 000 000 when you want milliseconds. a division by 1 000 would be sufficient.

Comment: Basically because I made several attempts and I must have messed with the numbers in the last one... anyway, you're answer seems to work, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your mistake is in your deviders :

```
long milliseconds   = (long) (timestamp / 1000) % 1000;
long seconds    = (((long) (timestamp / 1000) - milliseconds)/1000)%60 ;
long minutes    = (((((long) (timestamp / 1000) - milliseconds)/1000) - seconds)/60) %60 
long hours      = ((((((long) (timestamp / 1000) - milliseconds)/1000) - seconds)/60) - minutes)/60
```