# convert milliseconds to seconds, minutes without rounding

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert milliseconds to seconds and minutes in Java 1.4.2. I'm having trouble because my conversions are being rounded up. For example....

```
public String toString() {

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsedTimeMillis = (endTime - startTime);

    double seconds = (double) (elapsedTimeMillis / 1000) % 60 ;
    double minutes = (double) ((elapsedTimeMillis / (1000*60)) % 60);

    return 
        " elapsedTime: " 
        + " milliseconds:" + elapsedTimeMillis 
        + " seconds:" + seconds 
        + " minutes:" + minutes;

}
```

This returns results like...

*elapsedTime:  milliseconds:1392 seconds:1.0 minutes:0.0*

and

*elapsedTime:  milliseconds:742 seconds:0.0 minutes:0.0123667*

Instead I would like...

*elapsedTime:  milliseconds:1392 seconds:1.392 minutes:0.0232*

and

*elapsedTime:  milliseconds:742 seconds:0.742 minutes:0.01236667*

Seems like a simple question but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can someone help me with this.

thanks

Comment: It does no good to convert to double *after* you've done the division.

Comment: (But your computations are wrong anyway.  Better to compute integer seconds and compute fractions separately.)

Comment: Dear God, why are you using Java 4?

Comment: Check 1st answer of this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874048/from-milliseconds-to-hour-minutes-seconds-and-milliseconds .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use floating point arithmetics on division:

```
(elapsedTimeMillis/1000.0)
```

and

```
(elapsedTimeMillis/(1000.0*60))
```

correspondingly.

In other words:

```
double seconds =  elapsedTimeMillis / 1000.0;
double minutes = (elapsedTimeMillis / (1000.0 * 60)) % 60;
```

Comment: The seconds calculation is just plain wrong, and using 1000.0 doesn't solve the underlying problem, which is that floating-point shouldn't be used at all.

Comment: why is the seconds calcuation plain wrong? Can you please expand on this comment