# Conversion algorithm milliseconds to minutes correct?

Tags: milliseconds

This algorithm is pretty popular, but in some cases i do get some conflict with TimeUnit results.

```
   long millis = 12884983;
System.out.println(((millis / (1000 * 60)) % 60));
System.out.println(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis));
```

Prints:
34
214

Answer (score 1):

First line is wrong:

```
System.out.println(((millis / (1000 * 60)) % 60));
```

and should be

```
System.out.println((millis / (1000 * 60)));
```

The mod operation cuts off your result. If you calculate 214 % 60 you get 34.

Comment: thx, this should be edited then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874048/from-milliseconds-to-hour-minutes-seconds-and-milliseconds

Comment: No, the this is still true: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874048/from-milliseconds-to-hour-minutes-seconds-and-milliseconds I think you got confused about the representation what you want. 214 Minutes is 3 hours and 34 minutes....

Comment: 12884983ms cann be expressed as 214 minutes OR as 3 hours and 34 minuts which is exacly the same time span. You need to decide which way you want to express the time span. `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes` is just doing the first.