# discord.js v13 bot uptime

Tags: discord.js, uptime

I made some bot uptime code but got an error showing 52 years ago The code is below.

```js
const style = 'R'
const starttime = `<t:${Math.floor(client.readyAt / 1000)}` + (style ? `:${style}` : '') + '>'

client.on('messageCreate' , message=>{
    if(message.content == "!uptime"){
        message.reply(`uptime!\n uptime : ${starttime}`)
    }
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Uptime of Discord.JS bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49912703/get-uptime-of-discord-js-bot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting that outside of the event, where `client.readyAt` is `null`. When you divide null by anything except for 0, you get `0`. The result would then be `<t:0:R>`. You could either make this a function, or set it in the event

```js
function generateReadyTimestamp() {
  return `<t:${Math.floor(client.readyAt / 1000)}` + (style ? `:${style}` : '') + '>'
}
// ...
message.reply(`uptime!\n uptime : ${generateReadyTimestamp()}`)
```

Or, setting it inside the callback:

```js
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if(message.content == "!uptime"){
        const starttime = `<t:${Math.floor(client.readyAt / 1000)}` + (style ? `:${style}` : '') + '>'
        message.reply(`uptime!\n uptime : ${starttime}`)
    }
})
```